# How can I restore vim's classic behavior whereupon it saves the last edit mark?

Tags: vim

I'm very accustomed to typing `` `. `` when I open a file to resume editing where I last left off.

On the default Vim 7.3 that came with my new OS X 10.9 Macbook this behavior doesn't work... it says `E20: Mark not set`.  Any idea how to enable this?  When I type:

```
:set viminfo?
```

I see that viminfo appears to be set to something reasonable:

```
viminfo='100,<50,s10,h
```

[UPDATE: Turns out my .viminfo file was owned by root for some reason.  Using chmod to change owner back to myself solved the problem.]

Comment: Do you run Vim in "compatible" or "nocompatible" mode? Do you even have a `~/.viminfo` file?

Comment: Thanks for making me check the .viminfo file!  Turns out it was owned by root for some reason -- maybe while migrating files from the old machine.  Anyway I chmod'd the file so I'm the owner and voila it works.  Thanks

Comment: @Magnus, That can happen sometimes if you run vim with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your problem on my Ubuntu machine. The original output of `set viminfo?` was just like yours.

```
viminfo='100,<50,s10,h
```

After putting the  following line in my `.vimrc`, I was able to jump to the former cursor location using 
`` `. ``

```
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo
```

I got that line from this [vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session), where each part is also described.

**Update**: The OP already solved his problem, which was related to permissions on `.viminfo`, but I am leaving this answer up in case it helps future people who did not have that particular issue.

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately.  Thanks for the effort though!